# What SQL query would give me the percentage(%) of the houses sold?

Tags: sql-server

What SQL query would give me the percentage(%) of the houses sold price over list price for each:

" Area "," Build type" and "Month"?

the table is

```
{ Mls No, Build Type, Area code, List price, Sold price, Sold data }
```

But I need only :

```
percentage (%) of houses  "sold price " over List price for each:
    "Area code ", "Build type" and "Month"

MLS No.   Area  List Price  Contract    Price Sold  Date Sold   Building Type
N1959472  N11   329500      20/09/2010  317000      13/11/2010  Semi-Detac 
N1990464  N11   339000      08/11/2010  340000      17/11/2010  Apt
```

Comment: Please add more detail, it is not clear what you want to have accomplished.

Comment: @Hogan: [Multiple Listing Service.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_Listing_Service)

Answer (score 4):

You could `group by` the "per" fields, and calculate the percentage using aggregates, like:

```
select  Area
,       Buildtype
,       Month
,       100.0 * sum(case when SoldPrice > ListPrice then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)
from    YourTable
group by
        Area
,       Buildtype
,       Month
```

If there's no Month column, but only a date column, replace month with:

```
SQL Server:      datepart(month, SoldDate)
Oracle/MySQL:    extract(month from SoldDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a JOIN or a UNION, just put a CASE into the query, something like this:

```
select Area
     , Build_type
     , extract(month from sold_date) as month
     , SUM(case when sold_price > list_price then 1.0 else 0 end)
      /count(*) as pct_sold
  FROM theTable
 GROUP BY Area
        , build_type
        , extract(month from sold_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no column `Month`. You don't need a `join` or `union`, google for `GROUP BY`.

Comment: MLS No. Area List Price Contract Date Sold Price Sold Date House Type
N1959472 N11 329500 20/09/2010 317000 13/11/2010 Semi-Detac
N1990464 N11 339000 08/11/2010 340000 17/11/2010