# Query for percentage of the maximum soldprice over list price for each group

Tags: sql-server

I need to query for the maximum `Sold Price` over `List Price` for each `Area`, `Building Type` per `Month`.

For example, we have a Real Estate and we want to find:

What is the maximum and percentage of the `Sold Price` in which "Area" and what kind of `Building Type` sold per `Month`?

```
MLS No.   Area  List Price  Contract    Price Sold  Date Sold   Building Type
N1959472  N11   329500      20/09/2010  317000      13/11/2010  Semi-Detac 
N1990464  N11   339000      08/11/2010  340000      17/11/2010  Apt
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'percentage of sold price'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What SQL query would give me the percentage(%) of the houses sold?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785231/what-sql-query-would-give-me-the-percentage-of-the-houses-sold)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by 'percentage', but I'll show you how to group by month to get the max price. The percentage is probably an aggragation too, which you can add later.

```
select
  Area,
  HouseType,
  max(PriceSold) as MaxPriceSold
from
  YourTable
group by
  Area,
  HouseType,
  Year(DateSold),
  Month(DateSold)
```

Comment: Probably, it should be the percentage of MAX(PriceSold) over MAX(ListPrice) as per your solution. Just a guess, and it's based on the OP's other question, but seems to make some sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess at what you need. I think it accomplishes what you asked for at least. From what I got, you wanted to group by area and then building type. Within each group you wanted the max amount that the building type sold for each month, and the percentage of the sold price. "Percentage of the sold price" is completely ambiguous as far as I can tell (unless I'm missing something) so I took that to mean the percentage of a given building type in a given area made up sales for that group in that month. If any part of those assumptions are wrong just say so. Here's what I got:

```
DECLARE @RealEstate TABLE
(
    MLSNo CHAR(8) 
    , Area CHAR(3) 
    , ListPrice INT 
    , [Contract] DATE 
    , PriceSold INT
    , DateSold DATE
    , BuildingType VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT @RealEstate
VALUES ('N1959472', 'N11', 329500, '20100920', 329500, '20100920', 'Semi-Detac')
, ('N1990464', 'N11', 339000, '20101108', 339000, '20101108', 'Apt')
, ('N1990465', 'N11', 331350, '20101124', 331350, '20101124', 'Apt')
, ('N1990465', 'N11', 359840, '20100313', 359840, '20100313', 'Detac')
, ('N1990465', 'N11', 351230, '20100320', 351230, '20100320', 'Other Building')
, ('N1990468', 'N11', 376590, '20100328', 376590, '20100328', 'Outhouse')
, ('N1990468', 'N11', 374838, '20100315', 374838, '20100315', 'Detac')
, ('N1990469', 'N11', 351976, '20100328', 351976, '20100328', 'Detac')
, ('N1990470', 'N11', 348901, '20100303', 348901, '20100303', 'Other Building')
, ('N1990471', 'N11', 101685, '20100516', 101685, '20100516', 'Other Building')
, ('N1990472', 'N11', 359875, '20100909', 359875, '20100909', 'Apt');


DECLARE @Year INT = 2010;

WITH Aggregated AS
(
    SELECT
        Area
        , BuildingType
        , DATENAME(MONTH, DateSold) AS NameOfMonth
        , PriceSold
        --, MAX(PriceSold) OVER(PARTITION BY Area, BuildingType, DATENAME(MONTH, DateSold)) AS MaxForMonth
        , CAST((CAST(PriceSold AS DECIMAL) / (SUM(PriceSold) OVER(PARTITION BY Area, DATENAME(MONTH, DateSold))) * 100) AS INT) AS PercentageOfPriceSold
    FROM @RealEstate
    WHERE YEAR(DateSold) = @Year
)
, PivotedMax AS
(
    SELECT
        Area
        , BuildingType
        , ISNULL(January, 0) AS MaxSoldInJanuary
        , ISNULL(February, 0) AS MaxSoldInFebruary
        , ISNULL(March, 0) AS MaxSoldInMarch
        , ISNULL(April, 0) AS MaxSoldInApril
        , ISNULL(May, 0) AS MaxSoldInMay
        , ISNULL(June, 0) AS MaxSoldInJune
        , ISNULL(July, 0) AS MaxSoldInJuly
        , ISNULL(August, 0) AS MaxSoldInAugust
        , ISNULL(September, 0) AS MaxSoldInSeptember
        , ISNULL(October, 0) AS MaxSoldInOctober
        , ISNULL(November, 0) AS MaxSoldInNovember
        , ISNULL(December, 0) AS MaxSoldInDecember
    FROM Aggregated
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(PriceSold)
        FOR NameOfMonth IN
        (
            [January]
            , [February]
            , [March]
            , [April]
            , [May]
            , [June]
            , [July]
            , [August]
            , [September]
            , [October]
            , [November]
            , [December]
        )
    ) Pivoted
)
, PivotedPercent AS
(
    SELECT
        Area
        , BuildingType
        , ISNULL(January, 0)  AS PercentageOfSalesInJanuary
        , ISNULL(February, 0) AS PercentageOfSalesInFebruary
        , ISNULL(March, 0) AS PercentageOfSalesInMarch
        , ISNULL(April, 0) AS PercentageOfSalesInApril
        , ISNULL(May, 0) AS PercentageOfSalesInMay
        , ISNULL(June, 0) AS PercentageOfSalesInJune
        , ISNULL(July, 0) AS PercentageOfSalesInJuly
        , ISNULL(August, 0) AS PercentageOfSalesInAugust
        , ISNULL(September, 0) AS PercentageOfSalesInSeptember
        , ISNULL(October, 0) AS PercentageOfSalesInOctober
        , ISNULL(November, 0) AS PercentageOfSalesInNovember
        , ISNULL(December, 0) AS PercentageOfSalesInDecember
    FROM Aggregated
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(PercentageOfPriceSold)
        FOR NameOfMonth IN
        (
            [January]
            , [February]
            , [March]
            , [April]
            , [May]
            , [June]
            , [July]
            , [August]
            , [September]
            , [October]
            , [November]
            , [December]
        )
    ) Pivoted
)
SELECT
    PivotedMax.Area
    , PivotedPercent.BuildingType
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInJanuary
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInJanuary
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInFebruary
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInFebruary
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInJanuary
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInMarch
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInMarch
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInApril
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInApril
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInMay
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInMay
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInJune
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInJune
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInAugust
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInAugust
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInSeptember
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInSeptember
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInOctober
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInOctober
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInJanuary
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInNovember
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInNovember
    , PivotedMax.MaxSoldInDecember
    , PivotedPercent.PercentageOfSalesInDecember
FROM PivotedMax
INNER JOIN PivotedPercent
    ON PivotedPercent.Area = PivotedMax.Area
        AND PivotedPercent.BuildingType = PivotedMax.BuildingType
```

The sample data is all for one area but it should work fine for many. It can also be modified to work by area and take out the building type grouping. Hope that helps.

Comment: wowwwwwwwwwwwww Oh my God I can't believe  it !this is BOOK ,not Cod